# How do you add a country list field to Advanced Custom Fields?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Sadly WordPress doesn’t have a country list that can be accessed by various plugins in different scenarios. It does have a list of countries and cities in the time zone settings and WooCommerce installs its own country list available in setting up shops etc. Unfortunately a country list is not easily available in Advanced Custom Fields free or paid.

I found a free plugin on GitHub but it seems to either have a bug or is not yet ready for the 6.x series and it has no support. I also found a tutorial for making a country list plugin on Smashing Magazine (for 4.x) that led me eventually to an ACF example field type plugin template that should help me achieve my goal. However, it is so skimpy on instructions as to be useless to me not being a coder.

https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf-example-field-type

I followed all the instructions in the Read me and so far nothing shows in my available field types.

Can someone please take a look at the above-linked template and help guide me to getting a country dropdown list field?

I have a list with the codes and country names and also have it in a key/value pair array.

1. My two blockages are:Where do I place the folder with the various
   files? Adding thefolder to my site-specific plugin folder and
   placing the include include_once **DIR** .
   ‘/acf-FIELD-NAME/init.php’; in my functions file has no visible
   effect.
2. Where do I place the HTML form and the loop through the country
   list so as to generate the select dropdown?

When I paste my 200+ line country list in an ACF Select field type it works perfectly but as I have three instances to select a country on one form, this means copy and pasting the list for each rather than just using an ACF Country Select Type.

Thanks.